# Issues while parallelizing jobs in a multi-project job

Tags: maven, jenkins, parallel-processing

I'm trying to parallelize parametrized jobs from a Multi-Project one.

The fact is that the configurations of the jobs are the same. When I build my MP jobs the error can occur on a sub-job which is not always the same, it's really hazardous.... There is no logic in it

Did somenone encountered this error too ?

ERROR: Processing failed due to a bug in the code. Please report this to jenkinsci-users@googlegroups.com
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at hudson.maven.AbstractMavenBuilder.end(AbstractMavenBuilder.java:101)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:855)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:536)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1718)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:531)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)
project=hudson.maven.MavenModuleSet@3b3f4f26[Aggregator_XXX_(VERSIONING)]
project.getModules()=[hudson.maven.MavenModule@4d30311[Aggregator_XXX_(VERSIONING)/lu.ept.pom:ept-pom-aggregator-Admin-jar-1.5][Aggregator_XXX_(VERSIONING)/lu.ept.pom:ept-pom-aggregator-Admin-jar-1.5][relativePath:_poms\ept-pom-aggregator-Admin-jar-1.5], hudson.maven.MavenModule@60a3eba9[Aggregator_XXX_(VERSIONING)/lu.ept.pom:ept-pom-aggregator-Common-jar-1.5][Aggregator_XXX_(VERSIONING)/lu.ept.pom:ept-pom-aggregator-Common-jar-1.5][relativePath:_poms\ept-pom-aggregator-Common-jar-1.5], hudson.maven.MavenModule@2c1cebdb[Aggregator_XXX_(VERSIONING)/lu.ept.pom:ept-pom-aggregator-Common-jar-1.6][Aggregator_XXX_(VERSIONING)/lu.ept.pom:ept-pom-aggregator-Common-jar-1.6][relativePath:_poms\ept-pom-aggregator-Common-jar-1.6], hudson.maven.MavenModule@44778b0[Aggregator_XXX_(VERSIONING)/lu.ept.pom:ept-pom-aggregator-SOAApp-ear-was85][Aggregator_XXX_(VERSIONING)/lu.ept.pom:ept-pom-aggregator-SOAApp-ear-was85][relativePath:_poms\ept-pom-aggregator-SOAApp-ear-was85], hudson.maven.MavenModule@23c708ab[Aggregator_XXX_(VERSIONING)/lu.ept.pom:ept-pom-aggregator-SOAApp-jar-1.5][Aggregator_XXX_(VERSIONING)/lu.ept.pom:ept-pom-aggregator-SOAApp-jar-1.5][relativePath:_poms\ept-pom-aggregator-SOAApp-jar-1.5], hudson.maven.MavenModule@2ddd0e72[Aggregator_XXX_(VERSIONING)/lu.ept.pom:ept-pom-aggregator-SOAApp-jar-1.6][Aggregator_XXX_(VERSIONING)/lu.ept.pom:ept-pom-aggregator-SOAApp-jar-1.6][relativePath:_poms\ept-pom-aggregator-SOAApp-jar-1.6], hudson.maven.MavenModule@80f97da[Aggregator_XXX_(VERSIONING)/lu.ept.pom:ept-pom-aggregator-SOAApp-war-was85][Aggregator_XXX_(VERSIONING)/lu.ept.pom:ept-pom-aggregator-SOAApp-war-was85][relativePath:_poms\ept-pom-aggregator-SOAApp-war-was85], hudson.maven.MavenModule@41ca0966[Aggregator_XXX_(VERSIONING)/lu.ept.pom:ept-pom-aggregator-SOXX-ear][Aggregator_XXX_(VERSIONING)/lu.ept.pom:ept-pom-aggregator-SOXX-ear][relativePath:_poms\ept-pom-aggregator-SOXX-ear], hudson.maven.MavenModule@5e5d8ea8[Aggregator_XXX_(VERSIONING)/lu.ept.pom:ept-pom-aggregator-SOXX-jar-1.5][Aggregator_XXX_(VERSIONING)/lu.ept.pom:ept-pom-aggregator-SOXX-jar-1.5][relativePath:_poms\ept-pom-aggregator-SOXX-jar-1.5], hudson.maven.MavenModule@222b72db[Aggregator_XXX_(VERSIONING)/lu.ept.pom:ept-pom-aggregator-SOXX-war][Aggregator_XXX_(VERSIONING)/lu.ept.pom:ept-pom-aggregator-SOXX-war][relativePath:_poms\ept-pom-aggregator-SOXX-war], hudson.maven.MavenModule@76192577[Aggregator_XXX_(VERSIONING)/lu.ept.pom:ept-pom-aggregator-WebServices-ear-was85][Aggregator_XXX_(VERSIONING)/lu.ept.pom:ept-pom-aggregator-WebServices-ear-was85][relativePath:_poms\ept-pom-aggregator-WebServices-ear-was85], hudson.maven.MavenModule@37df5e23[Aggregator_XXX_(VERSIONING)/lu.ept.pom:ept-pom-aggregator-WebServices-jar-1.5][Aggregator_XXX_(VERSIONING)/lu.ept.pom:ept-pom-aggregator-WebServices-jar-1.5][relativePath:_poms\ept-pom-aggregator-WebServices-jar-1.5], hudson.maven.MavenModule@2c326e33[Aggregator_XXX_(VERSIONING)/lu.ept.pom:ept-pom-aggregator-WebServices-jar-1.6][Aggregator_XXX_(VERSIONING)/lu.ept.pom:ept-pom-aggregator-WebServices-jar-1.6][relativePath:_poms\ept-pom-aggregator-WebServices-jar-1.6], hudson.maven.MavenModule@7c5e1e09[Aggregator_XXX_(VERSIONING)/lu.ept.pom:ept-pom-aggregator-WebServices-jaxb][Aggregator_XXX_(VERSIONING)/lu.ept.pom:ept-pom-aggregator-WebServices-jaxb][relativePath:_poms\ept-pom-aggregator-WebServices-jaxb], hudson.maven.MavenModule@6bb72cf9[Aggregator_XXX_(VERSIONING)/lu.ept.pom:ept-pom-aggregator-WebServices-model][Aggregator_XXX_(VERSIONING)/lu.ept.pom:ept-pom-aggregator-WebServices-model][relativePath:_poms\ept-pom-aggregator-WebServices-model], hudson.maven.MavenModule@1c3b7171[Aggregator_XXX_(VERSIONING)/lu.ept.pom:ept-pom-aggregator-WebServices-war-was85][Aggregator_XXX_(VERSIONING)/lu.ept.pom:ept-pom-aggregator-WebServices-war-was85][relativePath:_poms\ept-pom-aggregator-WebServices-war-was85]]
project.getRootModule()=hudson.maven.MavenModule@44778b0[Aggregator_XXX_(VERSIONING)/lu.ept.pom:ept-pom-aggregator-SOAApp-ear-was85][Aggregator_XXX_(VERSIONING)/lu.ept.pom:ept-pom-aggregator-SOAApp-ear-was85][relativePath:_poms\ept-pom-aggregator-SOAApp-ear-was85]
FATAL: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at hudson.maven.AbstractMavenBuilder.end(AbstractMavenBuilder.java:101)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:855)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:536)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1718)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:531)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)

Comment: Which maven version do you use? Do you use Jenkins/Hudson (my assumption is Jenkins)? Which Jenkins version do you use? How have you called Maven and configured? Are you using up-to-date plugins?

Comment: I'm using Jenkins 1.596, Maven 3.2.5 and all my plugins are up-to-date !
I called maven from my local.
The fact is when I don't select ``execute concurrent builds if necessary`` everything is going well !